# How to save query values when searching? ASP.NET MVC 

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, pagination

I have such an action method:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Search(String filter, String value, Int32? page) {
    var set = new List<Employee>();
    switch(filter) {
    case "by-name": {
            set = this.repository.Get(
                e => (e.LastName + " " + e.FirstName + " " + e.MiddleName) == value
            ).ToList();
            break;
        }
        case "by-empn": {
            set = this.repository.Get(
                e => e.EmployeeNumber == value
            ).ToList();
            break;
        }
        default: return RedirectToAction("Search", "Employee"); 
    }

    ViewBag.SearchedEmployees = set.Count();
    return View(set.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, PageSize));
}
```

Search view is like this:

```
@if(Model.Count > 0) {
    foreach(var item in Model) {
        Html.RenderPartial("Employee.Card", item);
    }

    @Html.PagedListPager(
        Model,
        page => Url.Action("Search", new { page = page }),
        new PagedListRenderOptions {
            LinkToFirstPageFormat = "<< Beginning",
            LinkToPreviousPageFormat = "< Back",
            LinkToNextPageFormat = "Forth >",
            LinkToLastPageFormat = "End >>"
        }
    )
}
```

Search form is presented as a partial view:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Search", "Employee", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "search-form" }))
{
    <p>
        @Html.TextBox("value")
    </p>
    <p>
        @Html.RadioButton("filter", "by-name", true) By name <br/>
        @Html.RadioButton("filter", "by-empn") By empn <br/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="image" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Search.png")" />
    </p>
}
```

Problem: I have `N` page links. When I try to go to the second page I face an infinite loop of redirects. That's the way I implemented my action - default case is fired. So `filter/value` values are `null` on the second action call? Why? 
How do I refactor my search action?

Also how should I configure route for such an action?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

So should route for the search action look like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "{controller}/{action}/Page{page}/filter{filter}/val{value}",
    new { controller = "Employee", action = "Search" }
);
```

?

**EDIT 2**

So it is possible to write next:

```
page => Url.Action("Search", new { filter = ViewBag.SearchFilter, value = ViewBag.SearchValue, page = page }),
```

And inside a controller:

```
public ActionResult Search(String filter, String value, Int32? page) {

    ViewBag.SearchFilter = filter;
    ViewBag.SearchValue = value;
    // ...
}
```

Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So filter/value values are null on the second action call? Why?

Because their corresponding input fields are inside a separate form and are never sent to the server.

You seem to be using some custom `Html.PagedListPager` helper (the code for which you haven't shown) but I guess that this helper generates the page links as anchors and it simply doesn't take into account any current query string or POSTed values when generating those links. So the `href` of your pagination link looks like this `/SomeController/Search?page=5` instead of the correct one which would take into account those parameters which is `/SomeController/Search?page=5&filter=somefilter&value=somevalue`.

You can now easily understand why the `filter` and `value` parameters in your controller action are always null. It's because you never send them to the server when clicking on the pagination links.

So in order to resolve this issue you could modify this custom HTML helper that you are using to generate the pagination links to include those additional parameters. Or maybe the helper allows you to pass additional parameters? Check the documentation if this is some third party plugin that you are using.

Comment: 1) Please look at my edit; 2) I'm using Troy Goode's pagination list. I've written something like this (EDIT 2).

Comment: Yeah, this seems like a good way to generate the url yourself and include the 2 parameters. I would use a strongly typed view model instead of `ViewBag` but if you feel more comfortable with it keep using it.

Comment: Cool! Also I mentioned that when I make the first search request I get url like this `http://localhost:51126/Employee/Search/Page2?value=%D0%A6%D0%A2%D0%94&filter=by-dept&x=24&y=13`. And I don't understand where `x` and 'y' come from? How do I form my route for the corresponding action?

Comment: X and Y are the coordinates of the image where you clicked. You used an image submit button and according to the HTML specification those values are sent to the server by the user agent. They allow the server to know where exactly did the user click on the image button when submitted the form.